# Redmine plug-in fails at rake db:migrate_plugins

Tags: mysql, redmine

First post, so hope I'm in the right place.

While trying to install the Redmine plug-in 'Wiki Extensions', I keep getting stuck when I try to run the "rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV=production" command.

I am moving server and I'm in  bit over my head. Haven't found anything on Google that has helped me much, though I might have missed something.

I have pasted in the output with --trace:

```
(in /srv/www/vastpark.org/redmine)
** Invoke db:migrate_plugins (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate_plugins
Migrating engines...
Migrating acts_as_activity_provider...
Migrating acts_as_attachable...
Migrating acts_as_customizable...
Migrating acts_as_event...
Migrating acts_as_list...
Migrating acts_as_searchable...
Migrating acts_as_tree...
Migrating acts_as_versioned...
Migrating acts_as_watchable...
Migrating awesome_nested_set...
Migrating classic_pagination...
Migrating coderay-0.9.2...
Migrating gravatar...
Migrating open_id_authentication...
Migrating prepend_engine_views...
Migrating redmine_wiki_extensions...
==  CreateWikiExtensionsComments: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:wiki_extensions_comments)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
Mysql::Error: Table 'wiki_extensions_comments' already exists: CREATE TABLE 'wiki_extensions_comments' ('id' int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 'wiki_page_id' int(11), 'key_word' varchar(255), 'user_id' int(11), 'comment' text, 'created_at' datetime, 'updated_at' datetime) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing a backup on the wiki_extensions_comments table the removing it and rerunning the migration (and then restoring the table) using MySQL workbench or administrator connecting to the Redmine MySQL database, or you could move the plugin our of vendor/plugins directory and then run the migration, then copy it back.

Comment: Hey Josh, thanks for the tip, I will try it soon and get back to you.

Comment: I had this same issue on a plugin today. I just renamed the old tables to [table-name]-old then reran the migration and it worked fine. Then I checked to make sure new ones weren't a different structure and removed the news ones and renamed the old ones back the original table names. Running a migration after this even everything was peachy.

Comment: I've just done the same thing and that solved the question.
I have run into something tho, after moving them back I can run the rake script with no errors, but when I go to the Redmine wiki I get an Internal error. I post back after I figure out why.